# Vector Projection through a point and onto a plane

Tags: vector, 3d, point, projection, plane

[image: Vector Porjection through a point]

I need to calculate the location of the yellow star on the plane, in flat plane [Tangent Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space).

So first I need to project a vector from the eye, through the pink square, and find the resulting location on the plane (find the yellow star).

Everything is in tangent space already. So I know the location and direction of the eye, and the location of the pink square, in relation to the center of the plane (tangent space).

The resulting yellow star must be on the plane. So its position with respect to the direction of the blue arrow must be always zero. In the above image, it would have a positive value for its position with respect to the green and red arrows.

I've been trying to figure out how to do this using math such as [Vector Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection), but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Solve the equation of the line (of sight) for `z=0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the camera has 3d location vector **r** and direction vector **e**. The plane is defined by `z=0` which you use on the equation of the line

```
z = r_z + t * e_z = 0  } t = -r_z/e_z
```

the coordinate are then

```
x = r_x + t * e_x
y = r_y + t * e_y
```

I assume that everything is already expressed in the desired coordinate system with **blue** along the *z*-axis.

Comment: Thanks so much! I guess dropping out of high school at 16 didn't help me lol. Yes everything is in the tangent space / coordinate system. I assume **e** must be a _normalized_ vector. It'll take me a little bit to test this, but I'll be back later and mark this as answer if it works. :)

Comment: Actually **e** doesn't _have_ to be normalized, but it must have a non-zero _z_-axis component. If it is normalized then `t` is the distance from the _xy_ plane of the point.

Comment: I had to add `y = ((p.y < 0) ? -y : y);` not sure why. :) And for almost all my planes, I had to use swap x and y. Might be because in the end I'm reading a pixel from a texture that's on the plane, and it's probably true that I don't actually have everything in the "desired coordinate system". But overall, with minor tweaks, it is working! Thx :D

Comment: I think is a case you were looking for a more complicated solution using vector operations, when in reality it is simpler to consider components directly.

Comment: I'm taking the color of the pixel located at the yellow star, and drawing it onto the pixel that's located at the pink square. Both points are on different planes, with UVs stretched differently. The purpose is to allow to see through the pink square, like fake transparency. I'm still working to get it all working right. Your math is working though, it's the centerpiece. But, I don't see how I could do it without vector operations. :)